# Ruby undefined method `map' for CSV::open#<< (NoMethodError)

Tags: ruby, csv

This works but for some reason the comma is missing. `data` gets inserted as

```
GAURISH SHARMA
97
69
69
975
PASS
```

with each value written in new line. I wonder Where did the commas go? or do those have to manually inserted?

---

I am trying to write hash values using the following code

```
CSV.open("resultdata.csv", "a") do |csv|    
  h.each do |key, value|
    csv << value
  end
end
```

and here are the contents of the `h` hash

```
{:name=>"GAURISH SHARMA",
 :ca=>"97",
 :cb=>"69",
 :ba_lab=>"69",
 :bb_lab=>"69",
 :grand_total=>"975",
 :result=>"PASS"}
```

This code looks correct but upon running this code, generates the following errors:

```
/home/gaurish/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/csv.rb:1729:in `<<': undefined method `map' for "GAURISH SHARMA":String (NoMethodError)
    from /home/gaurish/Dropbox/code/projects/ra/result.rb:35:in `block (2 levels) in <main>'
    from /home/gaurish/Dropbox/code/projects/ra/result.rb:34:in `each'
    from /home/gaurish/Dropbox/code/projects/ra/result.rb:34:in `block in <main>'
    from /home/gaurish/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/csv.rb:1354:in `open'
    from /home/gaurish/Dropbox/code/projects/ra/result.rb:33:in `<main>'
```

Any idea what is wrong here?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

When you do `csv << value`, you are writing a string to a file.
The CSV library makes it possible to write an array to a file (in a certain form). The best way to get an array with all values from a hash is to use the `values` method btw. So:

```
require 'csv'
h = {:name=>"GAURISH SHARMA",
 :ca=>"97",
 :cb=>"69",
 :ba_lab=>"69",
 :bb_lab=>"69",
 :grand_total=>"975",
 :result=>"PASS"}

CSV.open("resultdata.csv", "a") do |csv|    
  csv << h.values
end
```

resultdata.csv will look like

```
GAURISH SHARMA,97,69,69,69,975,PASS
```

Comment: what If we want same result as in question?
GAURISH SHARMA
97
69
69
975
PASS
I mean If I want  each string on new line.

Answer (score 10):

Put `value` inside an array, like this:

```
CSV.open("resultdata.csv", "a") do |csv|    
  h.each do |key, value|
    csv << [value]
  end
end
```

**EDITED**

Everytime you use `csv << ["foo"]` it will insert "foo" in a new line. But if you do `csv << ["foo", "foo", "foo"]` you will get 3 "foo"s in the same line, separated by commas.

Knowing this, try to store all the values inside an array first, and after this use the `csv << your_values_array`. This will solve your problem.

Comment: Hey Thanks for reply, it worked but didn't fully solve the problem. now commas are missing. I have update the original question with the details

Comment: That `each` loop is entirely unnecessary in the second example, you can just do `csv << h.values` to get the same result.

Comment: Totally right :) I came to refactory that but guess it's to late.

Answer (score 2):

What `csv << value` is trying to do is append (`<<`) a new *row* onto the CSV. As such, it's expecting `value` to be an Array, not a String, with each element in the Array corresponding to a column/field of the row being appended. Thus, the following should work:

```
CSV.open("resultdata.csv", "a") do |csv|    
  h.each do |key, value|
    csv << [value]
  end
end
```

Comment: Hey Thanks for reply, it worked but didn't fully solve the problem. now commas are missing. I have update the original question with the details